# System.Data.SQLite design-time components in VS2012 targeting .NET 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, system.data.sqlite

My application is targeting .NET 4.0 because we plan to continue support for Server 2003 and Windows XP for now.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Entity Framework 4.4 (listed as 5.0 in NuGet) and System.Data.SQLite's ADO.Net provider v1.0.85.0.

I'm having trouble installing design-time components that (1) work in VS2012 and (2) generate Models and Code targeting .NET 4.0.  The System.Data.SQLite package that installs design-time components for VS2012 assumes .NET 4.5 and causes Entity Framework errors when generating a model from an existing database:

"The data type 'bigint' is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version; the column 'id' in table 'main.Message' was excluded."

"The data type 'binary' is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version; the column 'Message' in table 'main.Message' was excluded."

And so on...

My current work-around is to update the Entity Framework model using VS2010 but that's quite annoying.  Is there any way I can install the VS2010 design-time components on VS2012?  Alternatively can the VS2012 design-time components be configured to target .NET 4.0?

Comment: Same problem with .NET 4.5 project. Quite annoying indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same issue using .net 4.5. The problem seems to be related to sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.86.0.  when i install sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0   (84 instead of 86) it all works fine (in .net 4.5 atleast)

Comment: thank you so much. i downloaded 1.0.86.0 today and couldn't get it to work properly. i wasted a lot of time before i found your solution.

Comment: Download at : http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe